# Problem running GRASS 8.2 from R

Tags: r

I am attempting to use `initGRASS` in R and getting an error I haven't found in other answers so far.
The error is as follows:

```
sh: g.version: command not found
Error in system(paste("g.version", get("addEXE", envir = .GRASS_CACHE),  : 
  error in running command
```

The `initGRASS` call I am using is working on a collaborator's mac but not mine.

```
initGRASS(gisBase = '/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources',
          gisDbase = "/Users/philipmoffatt/grassdata",
          location = "grassR",
          mapset = "Rmaps",
          override = T)
```

I tried to verify where grass was installed with the following:

```
grass --config path
/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am getting the same error. Temporary locations with `initGRASS(gisBase = GRASS_INSTALLATION, home = tempdir(), SG = r, override = TRUE)` work where `r` is a SpatRaster object.

Comment: no luck so far, keep you posted.

Comment: After using Grass a little more, my understanding is that `initGRASS` is really only works well for temporary locations. Instead you should start R inside GRASS as described here: https://rsbivand.github.io/rgrass/articles/use.html

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem by using R from the terminal. The same code works when run on the command line. If anyone has recommendations about why this works please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and posted it on GitHub
https://github.com/rsbivand/rgrass/issues/85

Please see the issue post for a detailed explanation and solution.

Opening RStudio from GRASS command line solved my problem perfectly. （['open -na Rstudio'](https://community.rstudio.com/t/terminal-command-to-open-rstudio/2476/2)) There are also other workarounds listed in the post.

In addition, https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/grass-stats has been shared to be a convenient way to get accurate information on GRASS and rgrass.